# Grid From Tikz to Tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tkz-euclide

I have this code in Ti*k*Z which works, well but I need to do the same thing with `tkz-euclide`. My questions are:

1. How to make these in `tkz-euclide`?
2. How to change the x-axis name from x to M?
3. How to change the y-axis name from y to N?
4. How to make different range for x-axis and y-axis
   (in x-axis as from -2 to 12 and in y-axis from -20 to 100)?
5. How to draw horizontal bracket and vertical bracket?
6. How to draw arrows at the end of every side for x-axis and y-axis?
7. How to use `\tkzInit`, `\tkzAxeXY`, `\tkzGrid` for that?

```latex
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm,fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,snakes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xshift=9cm,
    xmin=-2,xmax=13.1,
    ymin=-30,ymax=105,
    grid={both},
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=cyan},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=cyan},
    axis lines={middle},
    minor tick num=1,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
     xlabel = {$M$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel = {$N$},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south east}
]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt] (O-label) at ($(O)+(-135:10pt)$) {$O$};

\addplot[color=black,domain=1.5:9,smooth,thick,-] {-3*(x-6)^2+4*x+64} node[right] (a) at (8,74){$f(x) $};
\addplot[color=red,domain=1:5,thick,-] {22*x-17} node[color=black,right] (b){$L$};
\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.3,anchor=center] (n) at (3,49) {};
\addplot[ color=black,smooth,thick,circle] (3,49) node(P)[left] {$D(P1,f(P1))$};
\addplot[color=cyan,domain=1:9.4,smooth,thick,-] {7*x+28}node[right] (d){};
\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.3,anchor=center] (g) at (8,84) {};
\addplot[ color=black,smooth,thick,circle] (8,84) node(P)[right] {$S(P2,f(P2))$};
\addplot[color=violet,domain=3:8,smooth,thick,-] {49}
node[pos=0.5,anchor=center,color=black,below,thick](f) {$P2-P1$};
\draw[snake=brace,mirror snake,red,thick] (3,49) -- (8,49);
\draw[color=violet,domain=8:8,thick,-] (8,49) -- (8,84)
node(yline1)[color=black,right] at (8,60) {$f(P2)-f(P1)$};
\draw[snake=brace,mirror snake,red,thick] (8,49) -- (8,84);
\draw[color=black,domain=8:8,smooth,thick,dashed] (3,0) -- (3,49) node(yline2)[below,yshift =-2.4 cm] {$P1$};
\draw[color=black,domain=8:8,smooth,thick,dashed] (8,0) -- (8,49) node(yline3)[below,yshift =-2.6 cm] {$P2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tangent-1]

Comment: i do not know how to insert the picture for this code

Comment: your code is  messy! I suggest using plain TikZ

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. I give a plain TikZ way for a similar figure without `grid` (it looks messy).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6mm,y=.5mm]
%\draw[violet!20] (-1.5,-15) grid[xstep=1,ystep=10] (12.5,115);
\draw[->] (-1.5,0)--(12,0) node[below=1mm]{$M$};
\draw[->] (0,-15)--(0,110) node[right]{$N$};
\path (0,0) coordinate (O) node[below left]{$O$};

\draw[smooth,thick] plot[domain=1:9.2] (\x,{-3*(\x-6)^2+4*\x+64}) node[right]{$f(x)$}; 
\draw[cyan,thick] plot[domain=1:9] (\x,{7*\x+28}); 
\draw[red,thick] plot[domain=1:5.5] (\x,{22*\x-17}) node[right]{$L$}; 
\path[blue]
(3,49) coordinate (D) +(-1.2,4) node[scale=.75]{$D(p_1,f(p_1))$} 
(8,84) coordinate (S) +(1.5,-1) node[scale=.75]{$S(p_2,f(p_2))$}
(D-|S) coordinate (T);
\fill[blue] (D) circle(2pt) (S) circle(2pt);
\foreach \i in {2,4,6,10}
\draw (\i,2)--(\i,-2) node[below,fill=white]{$\i$};
\foreach \j in {20,40,...,100}
\draw (.2,\j)--(-.2,\j) node[left,fill=white]{$\j$};

\draw[violet] (D)
--(T) node[below=2mm,pos=.5]{$p_2-p_1$}
--(S) node[right=1mm,pos=.3]{$f(p_2)-f(p_1)$};
\draw[dashed,violet] 
(D)--(D|-O) node[below]{$p_1$}
(T)--(T|-O) node[below]{$p_2$};
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt}] (T)--(D);
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=3pt}] (S)--(T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do the same thing with tkz-euclide and Grid using  \tkzInit, \tkzAxeXY, \tkzGrid.

Comment: @AA As said above, I don’t care your code. In fact, i don’t know how to use \tkzInit,....

Comment: No, i did not say that. your code is very good and profi,  but i need answers of my questions

Comment: @AAA As said above, I did not give an answer. Maybe some tkz experts will help you

Answer (score 0):

Since your question was about the grid and coordinate axes, here is what I gathered from the `tkz-euclid` manual

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=12.5, ymin=-2.5,ymax=10.5]
  \tkzGrid[color=cyan]
  \tkzDrawX[thick,>=latex,label=$M$]
  \tkzDrawY[thick,>=latex,label=$N$]

  \foreach \x in {-2,2,4,...,12}
  { \tkzDefPoint(\x,0){$\x$}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below]($\x$) }
  
  \foreach \y in {-20,20,40,...,100}
  { \tkzDefPoint(0,\y/10){$\y$}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left]($\y$) }

  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){$O$}
  \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-.5cm]($O$)
  
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]